# No route matches [GET] "/microposts/x" Chapter 10, Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial should be delete link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. I know this question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871875/no-route-matches-error-on-delete-of-micropost-in-chapter-11-of-hartls-ruby-on), but I have all the jquery links correct as verified by the fact that I can delete users without a problem but not the microposts. When I try the example in the browser and click the delete link(http://localhost:3000/microposts/253) on a micropost, even though the item does get deleted the browser says:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/microposts/253"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Test result:

```
Micropost pages micropost destruction as correct user should delete a micropost
     Failure/Error: expect { click_link "delete" }.should change(Micropost, :count).by(-1)
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/microposts/1"
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  root to: 'static_pages#home'...
```

Microposts delete link:

```
<%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                 confirm: "You sure?",
                                 title: micropost.content %>
```

Microposts controller:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

    def create
        @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
        if @micropost.save
          flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          @feed_items = []
          render 'static_pages/home'
        end
      end

      def destroy
        @micropost.destroy
        redirect_back_or root_path
      end

      private

        def correct_user
          @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by_id(params[:id])
          redirect_to root_path if @micropost.nil?
        end
end
```

I am unable to find the 3.2 tutorial repo to compare my sample_app to but I think I've followed the tutorial to the letter. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The problem is that you haven't updated your routes.  Inside your routes.rb file, you have `resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]`.  The route that its looking for is a :show to :microposts.

Without seeing your controller code, I suspect that after you delete the micropost, you are trying to redirect back to the micropost.  Either update your route to this: `resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy, :show]` or post up the details of your microposts controller.

Comment: Just added the Micropost controller to the question.

Comment: hm... what was the solution? I'm having this issue, I initially tried adding show to the routes, but since I got the "Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for MicropostsController" I came looking here. Also, I figure :show isn't necessary, as I'm issuing a delete request, right?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after restarting the rails server it worked fine for me.
[posting if anyone visits this page lately]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the problem is that your delete request goes as 'GET', But as per the REST conversions it should be a 'POST' request,

And I just created a sample app with Rails 3.1.3 and its delete link is as follows

In this case I have created a scaffold called User

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

You can check what is happening to your delete request by using [Firebug with Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: Delete link for the micropost is <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure?" %>

Answer (score 0):

I am working through the same tutorial, and am having the same problem. My analysis is that the problem is because we are using `redirect_back_or root_path` in the microposts controller (~/rails_projects/sample_app/app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb):

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
...
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy
...
  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    logger.debug "in MicropostsController.destroy:"
    logger.debug " root_path=#{root_path}"
    logger.debug " session[:return_to]=#{session[:return_to]}"
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
```

The output from the logger.debug statements shown is:

```
in MicropostsController.destroy:
 root_path=/
 session[:return_to]=/microposts/28
```

Recall that redirect_back_or is defined in sessions_helper.rb as:

```
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    clear_return_to
  end
```

So, the call to `redirect_back_or root_path` will result in:

```
redirect_to(/microposts/28)
```

I'm a newbie here, but I think the default action is GET; at least, that's consistent with what I'm seeing, i.e. this is why we are posting a GET to /microposts/28.

Meanwhile, in routes.rb, we have defined the resource microposts to only support create and destroy actions:

```
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Of course, we don't want to GET the micropost we just deleted; we want to re-render (or re-direct?) back to the page from which we came. As evidence that this analysis is correct as far as it goes, I found that calling `redirect_to root_path` instead of `redirect_back_or root_path` "works", in that the micropost gets deleted (after popup confirmation), and puts the user back on the home page (showing the deleted micropost is gone).

I have now changed my as follows, so that the page from which the delete action was invoked re-appears:

```
  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy 
    redirect_to request.referer
  end
```

I also changed my definition of `SessionsHelper#store_location`:

```
  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath if ['show', 'edit'].include?action_name
  end
```

So, only 'show' and 'edit' actions attempt to resume after login.